# Не работает аккаунт разработчика.

Tags: ios, swift, apple

Моя команда подключила меня в itunes connect но почему то когда я перехожу на developer.apple.com не могу получить ни сертификаты, ни другие атрибуты разработчика. Так че в itunes connect все отображается нормально и к команде я привязан. А вот на developer.apple.com команду не видно. Как можно решить эту проблему, т.к к сожалению прямой поддержки для разработчиков у apple нет. 
Вместо пункта "Welcome" должен быть пункт "overview" но он не появляется. И apple предлагает мне оплатить аккаунт заново. Скриншот itunes connect[image: ][1]]

Comment: Либо с электронной почтой напутали либо права не дали.

Comment: А что видит админ команды, когда заходит в раздел people аккаунта на developer.apple.com? Видит ли он там Вас в списке, и в какой роли?

Answer (score 1):

Приглашение для Developer и приглашение для iTunes Connect - два разных приглашения.

По приглашению в iTunes Вы можете/не можете в зависимости от роли публиковать/обновлять приложения и многое другое.
Вам нужно еще одно приглашение, только для developer.